# Built-in help stopped working

Tags: documentation

At some point recently, the built-in help seems to have disappeared on my copy of Mathematica. When I try to use it, the help window has a message like "Your search - GraphLayout - in Documentation Center did not match any documents."

I *think* this started after I loaded some module with >> recently, but I forget which one it was.

Any ideas on how to resolve this? (Ideally without nuking all my options with a reset, but if I have to, so be it.)

Comment: Does this persist even after you restart Mathematica or quit the `"Local"` kernel?

Comment: Also try typing in the direct URI in the top bar. I bet the ``"DocumentationSearch`"`` package is just screwed up. E.g. type `ref/Plot` or whatever

Comment: Yep! `ref/whatever` seems to work. Is there a way to fix it for good? And yes, it persists through restarts.